# Подключение Swiper через npm

Tags: node.js, swiper

Хочу подключить Swiper через npm. Я сделал как в инструкции, все установил. Использую я node.js, в проекте создалась папка node_modules, а в ней и папка swiper. Но когда я прописываю данный скрипт, то ничего не работает, а браузер ругается на третью строчку кода. В чем может быть проблема?
P.S. Знаю, что можно через CDN подключить, но хотелось бы данный способ рассмотреть, ведь только начал изучать Node.js и хочу все это дело попрактиковать.

```
// import Swiper JS

import Swiper from 'swiper';
// import Swiper styles
import 'swiper/css';

const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
    // Optional parameters
    direction: 'horizontal',
    loop: true,
    autoplay: {
        delay: 5000,
    },
});
```